# Specific Phone number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a regex for a phone number that takes the following forms using Javascript:

```
0610101010 => 10 digits that starts with 06 or 05.

+212565656566 => (+) followed by 212 then another 9 digits.
```

Thank You.

Comment: Yes there is. Those are extremely simple rules and you can easily google for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^(0(6|5)\d{8}|\+212\d{9})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
/0(5|6)[0-9]{8}|\+212[0-9]{9}/
```

**Explained:**

```
/ - The start of the regex

0 - Matches a zero

(5|6) - Matches a five or six

[0-9]{8} - Matches eight characters in the range zero to nine

| - Second expression starts here

\+212 - Matches a plus followed by 212

[0-9]{9} - Matches nine characters in the range zero to nine

/ - End of regex
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.